# Compact Framework Charting

Tags: excel, .net-3.5, compact-framework, graph

I'm doing an app in .NET Compact Framework 3.5 and I need to do some charting (xy, bar graph, pie and so on and stuff)...

Is there any open source library to do so?  Which Excel classes should i call to do so?

thanks in advance

Comment: Pocket Excel has zero automation model, so there is no way to use it programatically.  Abandon an hope of using it for graphing and look at a commercial offering.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather good open source graphing library for .NET - ZedGraph - http://zedgraph.org/wiki/ - I have used it many times in .NET applications.

Comment: It doesn't look like this one supports .NET CF.

Comment: Still,i belief it uses little more than the basic .NET drawing libraries - a simple rename of the namespaces used may suffice (granted, I haven't written a drawing app in CF).

Comment: .NET CF only supports integer pixel position (with a few exceptions), a fullframework library probably uses floating point positioning.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any open source libraries for .NET CF.
There are a few commercial ones available though:

- [Mooseworks Graph Control](http://www.mooseworkssoftware.com/graph.htm) (there is an option to buy it with the source code)
- [Steema Teechart](http://www.steema.com/products/teechart/net/specifications.html)
- [Resco CompactChart](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/CompactChart.aspx)